# standalone program for MEX file in linux

Tags: linux, matlab, mcc

I am trying to make executable files of MEX file in linux which uses image acquisition tool inside it. I used

```
mcc -mv filename
```

but getting Defun error msg. saying-

```
Depfun error: 'Unexpected Standard exception from MEX file. What() is: ..' Error using    
mcc Error executing mcc, return status = 1 (0x1).
```

Can you please help me out telling how can I make executable files for .m files which uses image acquisition tool in linux.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution, but this is duplicate of your previous question: [mcc -mv in linux machine R2013a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335223/mcc-mv-in-linux-machine-r2013a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in R2013a. I got an email from the matlab centre to replace the 'depfun.opts' file with a new version.

you can find the 'depfun.pots' file in the attachment here [in this bug report](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/951485)